# Changing Hashtable value of particular key

Tags: c#, .net

When user click on confirm and review button respactive(key ,value) pair is getting stored in hashtable,when user click on review button than that particular list item elments color is red ,what I want is if (key,value) pair is added using review button than I want to change its value if user clicks on confirm button ,In short in this (key ,value) pair I am storing (question,answer) so if user is not sure about answer than he click on review ,and later he should be able to change its answer and mark as confirm so this list item elements color gets change to green ,how can i do this

```
 private void AddtoHashTabl(string key, string value)
            {
                if (hashtable.ContainsKey(key))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    hashtable.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
    private void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string Q = "";
                string A = "";
                listView1.Items[Convert.ToInt16(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text) - 1].BackColor = Color.Green;

                var q = Convert.ToInt16(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
                var selectedQuestion = questions[q - 1];
                Q = selectedQuestion.Id;
                if (radioButton12.Checked == true)
                    A = "1";
                else if (radioButton11.Checked == true)
                    A = "2";
                if (radioButton10.Checked == true)
                    A = "3";
                if (radioButton9.Checked == true)
                    A = "4";

                AddtoHashTabl(Q, A);
            }
    private void Review_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string Q = "";
                string A = "";
                listView1.Items[Convert.ToInt16(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text) - 1].BackColor = Color.Red;

                var q = Convert.ToInt16(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
                var selectedQuestion = questions[q - 1];
                Q = selectedQuestion.Id;
                if (radioButton12.Checked == true)
                    A = "1";
                else if (radioButton11.Checked == true)
                    A = "2";
                if (radioButton10.Checked == true)
                    A = "3";
                if (radioButton9.Checked == true)
                    A = "4";

                AddtoHashTabl(Q, A);
            }
```

Thanks in advance for Any help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the indexer:

```
hashtable[key] = value;
```

That will set *or* add a value - so you can replace any `AddtoHashTabl` calls with just that indexer setter call.

Note that you'd be better off using a generic collection such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` if at all possible. The non-generic collections are rarely useful these days.

EDIT: To know where the value came from the review or confirm button, I would suggest having a *separate* collection (e.g. a `HashSet<string>`) of "confirmed responses". Or even simply two separate hashtables, one for each button. Alternatively, you could have an `Answer` class which contained both the value and its status as confirmed or not.

Comment: yes I can use indexer but how I can check that I am storing value from confirm button or review button,because if It is using confirm button than it should not allow to change that value,and can you please show how I can use  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @Durga: Ah, I see. Hang on...

Comment: If I use 2 saperate hashtables than I need to transfer that changed value from review hashtable to confirm hashtable how can i do this and could I get combined count number of those 2 saperate hashtables?

Comment: @Durga: Well what have you tried? I'm afraid I'm not going to spoon-feed you all the code - you really need to think about it for yourself.

Comment: I tried taking two saperate `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and stored values of different buttons in different dictionary,but how do i get status of review values using answer class and  combined count of both dictionaries now?

Comment: Ok I got It ,Thanks For your responce